# Combine two videos using Go and FFmpeg

Tags: go, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi

I have two videos, Video A && Video B. I want to combine both videos to a new video C using golang. I tried FFmpeg, but I am unable to cross compile it for ARM devices and getting error message.

> /usr/local/ffmpeg/lib/libavdevice.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Please advise.
Opening two media player at once is not an option. With amd64 I compile without having any issue.

Comment: Please clarify, how exactly you want to combine them.

Comment: Video A will be displayed on upper left side on Video B. Video A coordinates will be X=0, Y=0, Size (100,100)...

Comment: Probably the compiler is using ffmpeg library for the host computer not the ffmpeg library for RPI. You must provide ffmpeg library for Raspberry Pi. Or, download golang for RPI (arm version) then compile your go in the RPI.

Comment: Compiler is already configured for  CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc  devices with CGO_ENABLED=1.

Comment: Which go wrapper did you use? For example, in [goav](https://github.com/giorgisio/goav#installation) you need to define several environment variables *before* installing the wrapper, then proceed the installation. Also, make sure to set `GOOS=linux` and `GOARCH=arm` during installation/compilation.

Comment: Sorry for late replay. I am using gmf wrapper for ffmpeg. After compiling I am getting below error

github.com/3d0c/gmf

/usr/local/ffmpeg/lib/libavdevice.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

------------------------------------------------------------
Environment variables are as follows 
export GOOS=linux
export GOARCH=arm
export CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
export CGO_ENABLED=1